# How to align my left side bar

Tags: wordpress

How to align my sidebar to be vertically align with the header text `"E"` and my main content area has `960px`, I want it to be in the center.

And how I eliminate the gap between the sidebar and the header, I've use `topmargin="0"` on the `sidebar.php`, but it doesn't work.

I attached a sample image link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cd6n.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the menu inside a div and use right: 30% or something. Can you make a working example so I can further look into

Answer (score 0):

This usually solves problem like the one you have. Centers the page within a `#wrapper` id. The sidebar will follow the "E" but some minor changes may be needed. You should consider read about css :) Hope this helps

```
#wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 960px
}
```

Comment: paste your code, there are some minor changes that have to be made I belive

Answer (score 0):

If your main content area ( should be div with id="wrapper") has width of 960px, then the div inside that main div should also have a width (but smaller) let's say 700px, now you should put margin: 0 auto; and it will be in the middle.
About the gap, don't use topmargin="0", it's margin-top: 0;
But it look like it's padding gap, so put padding-top: 0;
I hope you write this in youre .css file ;) 
Read about css it' not hard it's easy and very very useful.
Hope I helped you.